# Custom top level navigation - will it affect site application searches?

Tags: navigation

Our intranet site is going to have a approximately 6-10 site collections all of which are going to have custom navigation and branding. We have found it easiest to brand the navigation by creating a custom top level navigation and setting the links to the site collections vs. creating a global navigation.

My question is will this affect web application searches across site collections?